# Laravel Redirect::withInput not working with put() method

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, put

I have a form that I check with the validator, and if it fails, I redirect to the page which contains the form, but I want to keep filled fields. So I use `withInput(Input::all())` in both store (which use post method) and update (which use put method) functions. It only works with store, not update.

That returns me the "no page found" error, whereas when I refresh, the page is found.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show some of your code. The store and update method for exemple?

Answer (score 0):

That's because a redirect is performed by a `302` request with a `Location` header. The browser will know to do a `GET` request to the `URL` inside the `Location` header. There's no option for a HTTP verb.

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (search for section 10.3.3) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

Hope this clarifies things for you.